# How to pull records based on count comparison of value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, where-clause

Pardon the title please but I did not know what to write. So here is what I have -

`CUSTOMER` (`KEY, IDENT, DEBIT_CREDIT`)

```
1,1000,'D'
2,1000,'C'
3,1001,'D'
4,1000,'D'
5,1000,'D'
.
.
.
```

I want to write a SQL Server query to pull the same `IDENT` where count of 'D' is greater than count of 'C'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First:

```
SELECT IDENT
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY IDENT
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT_CREDIT = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT_CREDIT = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Second:

```
SELECT IDENT
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY IDENT
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT_CREDIT = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) =
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT_CREDIT = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```